# Allergic to Protein supplements

Tags: muscle, protein, gym, muscle-mass

I'm allergic to Coco (I can't eat chocolate or coffee ) if I take any whey Protein or anything like SSN OR any kinda powdered supplements within 2days my Asthama gets high, I get lots of cough and cold.

I have been doing gym since last 4.5yrs 
I have a perfect fit lean body with muscles. I'm 5'9ft weight 67kg. 27yrs male.

Can you please suggest me how can I get more muscle and gain more weight. And any Protein diet. I don't eat much nonveg except eggs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaining mass is a product of a excess food and lifting regularly.

Gaining lean muscle is slightly harder.

My top tips:

- Eat regular small meals: 4-6 moderate meals a day, try to stack up on protein (egg, meat, fish), carbs (potatoes (baked preferrably - not deep fried) rice and pasta (opt for wholemeal)) + VEGGIES (yes you need them, the nutrients from veg is essential, try boiling carrots etc)
- Adjust your training program, try regular (4/5 times p/w), add variety (change the way you train), for size go for a rep range of 6-8 on a challenging weight.

Comment: I just go gym 2 times in a week. I will try to increase reps.

Comment: Going twice a week is fine, depending on work I may manage to make it 2-3 times. The important thing is that you train properly on these days. Start with a 5-10 min warm up (very important), then do all your big lifts (deadlift, leg press, bench, shoulder press, pull up etc) this should take up about 40% of your workout, after this just work your smaller muscles. I've been doing this for some time and have seen great gains but you must ensure that you change your routine regularly - this keeps your body sharp as it does not get too settled with a particular workout.

Comment: I do 1 body part in the day. I will try to add more workout and also increase my diet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To gain weight generally requires you to gain both fat and muscle.  The body generally doesn't partition all calories to the muscle (unless you are in your teens with a very lucky hormonal profile or you are taking steroids).  The general rule is 1 lb of fat for 1 lb of muscle (1:1 partitioning), also you will probably gain a lb of water and glycogen.

If you aren't allergic to dairy - you might want to do 'gallon of milk a day' or 'half gallon of milk a day' - that can bump up your calories to ensure you can gain weight, ensures adequate protein, and is easy to adhere to.

http://stronglifts.com/gomad-milk-squats-gallon-gain-weight/

Good article on maximum potential weight gain here and how much muscle you can expect to gain per month based on how much training you've done previously, age, gender and other factors.

http://www.bodyrecomposition.com/muscle-gain/whats-my-genetic-muscular-potential.html

Comment: Yes milk product are fine.  Only Coco and packaged powdered products I have allergy to